# Error Message : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2.dll'

Tags: .net, asp.net, dll, iis-6, expression-encoder

I face some problems while I host my web application(which is a PowerBuilder V12.0 .Net Web Appliaction Developed By PB V12.0 Classic or Migrated from Old PB Versions as the project files are Converted to ASP.Net *.aspx files) in IIS V6.0 on Windows Server 2003and After Installation of .Net Framework Version 4.0 to match the web application which requires .Net Framework 2.0+

The Error Message I get is as follows:-

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Description:
```

An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details:
```

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

```
Source Error:
```

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

```
Stack Trace:
```

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +39
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +144
       System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
       System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46
.....

I need a quick solution for that problem and Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is solved when putting the needed DLL files only and deleting other unnecessary DLL files. It was a problem of interfered and corrupted DLL files.**

Comment: Can you please share which dll you delete to make it work as I am also getting the same issue

Comment: This answer doesn't really help anyone. How did you delete the DLLs? How did you deem them unnecessary?